# Why am I getting a Django NoReverseMatch error?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to send an activation email to users when signing up, but I keep getting a NoReverseMatch error when trying to render the URL in the template.

The error I get is:

```
Reverse for 'user_activation' with keyword arguments '{'uidb64': 'MiC', 'token': 'aeue9g-3a31bdff969c41c0bb1d3775a1fa98ac'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['account/activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$']
```

**urls.py**

```
from .views import *
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', user_activation_view, name='user_activation'), # user activation view
]
```

**template.txt**

```
{% autoescape off %}
To activate your account ({{ user.email }}), please click the link below:

{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'user_activation' uidb64=uid token=token %}

If clicking the link above doesn't work, you can copy and paste the URL in a new browser
window instead.

If you did not make this request, please ignore this email.
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: you have more characters than is stated in your regex pattern

Comment: Your token is too long to be matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern for the token variable is:

```
<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20}
```

THis thus means that there are two sequence of `[0-9A-Za-z]` characters: one with one to thirteen characters, and one with one to twenty characters, and these are separated by a hyphen.

Your token however has:

```
'aeue9g-3a31bdff969c41c0bb1d3775a1fa98ac'
\__ __/ \_____________ ________________/
   v                  v
 6 chars           32 chars
```

So this does not match the specifications. If you want to accept this token, you can alter the pattern, for example to:

```
<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,32}
```